# How to define custom sort in Qlik Sense?

Tags: sorting, bar-chart, qliksense

I have a field [Payment Timing] storing values from -200 to 200. [Payment Timing] is to be used as the dimension of a bar chart.

In order to group the extreme values together, I have set the dimension to be

```
=If([Payment Timing]<-9,'<-9',If([Payment Timing]>9,'>9',[Payment Timing]))
```

However, if I sort the dimension based on [Payment Timing], '<-9' and '>9' will appear in the middle of the axis, which they should appear at the left and and right end respectively.

I learn from other websites that I can define the sort order in the load script like this:

```
PaymengTiming_Sort:
Load * Inline
[
Payment Timing,
<-9
-9
-8
-7
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>9
];
```

But this failed to load.

May I know how should I modify my script, or Qlik Sense does not support this?

Answer (score 0):

The '<-9' and '>9' are interpreted as text, while the others are presented as numbers. So when you ask Qlik to sort, it will not happen as you intend, because Qlik will sort it alphabetically or numerical.

An option can be to add a second column of data to your sort order table. Then you can sort numerically, but use the *Desc* field for the smooth display.

[xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdCd7.png)